# FFmpeg : using more than 15 audio streams

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, audio-streaming

I encountered a problem with video encoding. Here it the command I use to create a video.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i /Users/Images/image_%03d.png -ss 0.0 -t 3.333 -i /Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav -ss 0.0 -t 3.5 -i /Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav -filter_complex [1] volume=0.0dB,aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo [a1]; [a1]adelay=0.0|0.0,apad[b1]; [2] volume=0.0dB,aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo [a2]; [a2]adelay=0.0|0.0[b2]; [b1][b2]amerge=2[a] -map 0:v -map [a] -b:v 3200k -c:v libopenh264 -c:a aac -ac 2 /Users/Movies/output.mp4
```

It works fine with 0~15 audio files(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5...), I got errors when I have more than 15 audios.
Here is the output.

> `ffmpeg version N-90220-g69995a9 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
>     configuration: --enable-libopenh264
>     libavutil      56.  8.100 / 56.  8.100
>     libavcodec     58. 13.102 / 58. 13.102
>     libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
>     libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
>     libavfilter     7. 12.100 /  7. 12.100
>     libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
>     libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
>   Input #0, image2, from '/Users/Images/image_%03d.png':
>     Duration: 00:00:04.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
>       Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 200x343, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
>   Input #1, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #2.0 : mono
>   Input #2, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #3.0 : mono
>   Input #3, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_03.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #3:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #4.0 : mono
>   Input #4, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_04.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #4:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #5.0 : mono
>   Input #5, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #5:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #6.0 : mono
>   Input #6, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #6:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #7.0 : mono
>   Input #7, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #7:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #8.0 : mono
>   Input #8, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #8:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #9.0 : mono
>   Input #9, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #9:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #10.0 : mono
>   Input #10, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #10:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #11.0 : mono
>   Input #11, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #11:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #12.0 : mono
>   Input #12, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #12:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #13.0 : mono
>   Input #13, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #13:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #14.0 : mono
>   Input #14, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #14:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #15.0 : mono
>   Input #15, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #15:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #16.0 : mono
>   Input #16, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #16:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #17.0 : mono
>   Input #17, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #17:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #18.0 : mono
>   Input #18, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #18:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #19.0 : mono
>   Input #19, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_01.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.37, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #19:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #20.0 : mono
>   Input #20, wav, from '/Users/Sounds/Info_02.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:03.55, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #20:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Stream mapping:
>     Stream #1:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #2:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #3:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #4:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #5:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #6:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #7:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #8:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #9:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #10:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #11:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #12:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #13:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #14:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #15:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #16:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #17:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #18:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #19:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #20:0 (pcm_s16le) -> volume (graph 0)
>     Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libopenh264))
>     amerge (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
>   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   [image2 @ 0x7fcd8f002200] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
>   [libopenh264 @ 0x7fcd8f185400] [OpenH264] this = 0x0x7fcd8e612e90, Warning:bEnableFrameSkip = 0,bitrate can't be controlled for RC_QUALITY_MODE,RC_BITRATE_MODE and RC_TIMESTAMP_MODE without enabling skip frame.
>   [Parsed_amerge_79 @ 0x7fcd8e424580] No channel layout for input 1
>   [Parsed_amerge_79 @ 0x7fcd8e424580] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
>   [auto_resampler_20 @ 0x7fcd8e437b00] [SWR @ 0x7fcd8eb50a00] Input channel layout '40 channels (FL+FR+FC+LFE+BL+BR+FLC+FRC+BC+SL+SR+TC+TFL+TFC+TFR+TBL+TBC+TBR+DL+DR+WL+WR+SDL+SDR+LFE2)' is not supported
>   [auto_resampler_20 @ 0x7fcd8e437b00] Failed to configure output pad on auto_resampler_20
>   Error reinitializing filters!
>   Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
>   Error while processing the decoded data for stream #20:0
>   Conversion failed!`

Is there a limitation on file number?

Comment: The number "15" suggests that somewhere 4 bits are used, with one special value (probably 0)... but that's a guess.

Comment: What is the intended channel layout of the merged output?

Comment: @Gyan to one audio stream.

Comment: Yes, but what channel layout? Mono, Stereo, 7.1 ..etc?

Comment: @Gyan 2 channels AAC

Answer (score 1):

Use `amix` twice, before `amerge`.

Feed half the audio inputs to one `amix`; the other half to 2nd `amix`. Then `amerge` the two results.

Comment: Do I always need two `amix`? if I have 30 audios then I separate them to 15,15?

Comment: One amix for each output channel.